# Using Volatile.Read to avoid a lock on read

Tags: c#, multithreading, volatile

I'm writing a low-level keyboard hook in C# and my top priority for it is to avoid random, non-deterministic delays, such as from GC. My second priority is to make it run as fast as possible -- it's a "nice-to-have", not a "must-have".

My program has a thread for each "subscriber" to keyboard events. One subscriber thread can subscribe to multiple keyboard events. Only the subscriber can modify its own subscription, i.e. one thread is not allowed to subscribe or unsubscribe another thread.

The logic for my keyboard hook is:

1. Determine what keyboard event we're processing.
2. Look up the subscribers for that event.
3. Put the event in each subscriber's queue.

My current idea for step 2 is to get the subscriber info from a ConcurrentDictionary. Here's the simplified version of HotkeySubscriberInfo:

```
class HotkeySubscriberInfo
{
    private ISet<Subscriber> _subscribers;
    private Subscriber[] _memoizedSubscriberEnumeration;
    private object _writeMutex;
    private object _readMutex;
}
```

The HotkeySubscriberInfo would be mutated like this:

```
lock (_writeMutex)
{
    // add or remove a subscriber
    Subscriber[] memoized = subscribers.ToArray();
    lock (_readMutex)
    {
        _memoizedSubscriberEnumeration = memoized;
    }
}
```

The keyboard hook would just lock the `_readMutex`, get the array into a local variable and do a for loop over it.

My question is: can I get rid of `_readMutex` and use `Volatile.Read` in the keyboard hook? I am aware that this means that the keyboard hook doesn't always get the "fresh" value "instantly", but it's acceptable behavior as long as the value is not too stale (e.g. the subscriber unsubscribed, a whole second passed before someone pressed the hotkey and the subscriber gets the hotkey anyway because the subscriber list was stale).

Comment: "not too stale" is the vague kind of qualification that threading race bugs love.  If that's okay then just don't lock at all, updating an array reference is already atomic.  Micro-optimizing this code is quite pointless btw, keyboard events operate at human time.  And hopefully you don't install a new hook once a microsecond.  From pressing the key to seeing the character appear on the screen takes 15 milliseconds, give or take.  That it now takes 14.999995 milliseconds is something you cannot possibly see.

Comment: @HansPassant Yes, it actually is okay for the value to be stale, as long as it's not perceivably stale. Although I agree that micro-optimizing this code is probably pointless, there are two reasons why I'm considering it: 1) a keyboard hook, according to docs, has a limited time to run before Windows disconnects it, and 2) I want to learn more about "lockless" techniques in general. I'm not necessarily going to eliminate the lock, but I'm trying to learn from people like you, who know more about these things.